# How do I access array elements when I create the array with array = Array("first", "second", "third")

Tags: vba

I would like to use the Array function to fill an array. That works fine but once filled, I can't access the individual array element with array_name(index).

```
Dim letters as string, first_letter as string
letters = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
first_letter = letters(0)
```

Comment: You will need to create a [mcve] which includes the smallest amount of code to recreate the problem.

Comment: `Dim letters As Variant` (and the next line has an extra `)` at the end that needs to be removed.)

Comment: `Dim letters() as string`

Comment: @KL-1 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function   `Array()` returns a "variant containing an array", so `letters() as String` would get a type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

The Below works perfectly for me.

```
Sub TestingArray()

Dim letters() As Variant
Dim first_letter As String

letters = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
first_letter = letters(0)

'Testing all works

Dim I As Integer

Debug.Print first_letter
For I = 0 To 4
    Debug.Print letters(I)
Next I

End Sub
```